# `requests` returning different results for the same script if run both locally and on the cloud

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to send a request to [this](https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/) link and get its HTML content in a Python script. I am using `requests` library. The script runs perfectly well locally and gets the HTML content.

This script is just a test to make sure everything is working fine before I use another script to scrape that same link. This scraper would run for 2-3 days so I obviously wanted to run it on the cloud.

So, when I used that test script on a VM instance of Google Cloud Platform, it is getting the contents of a special page of the website which is used for IPs that are blacklisted. So this means that GCP's servers are blacklisted by the website. How can it be blacklisted if I have never used GCP before for web scraping?

How can I make sure that everything works as expected? Here is my code which checks if the HTML content is for a correct page or the incorrect one (The blacklist page contains the word 'engineers' in the body, so I am searching for that word to identify the page type):

```
import requests

base = 'https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/'

headers = {}  ## my headers go here. Without them, even locally, the script won't work

r = requests.get(base, headers=headers)
HTML = str(r.content)

if 'engineers' in HTML:
    print('You landed on blacklisted page')
else:
    print('Successful')
```

I also deployed this same script on Streamlit Cloud and it did not work there too. So I am guessing it is some kind of protection imposed by the website to deny all cloud servers.

Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 reasons

- Either the websites has already blacklisted all the public IP range of all cloud provider
- Or the IP that you use has been already used by another cloud customer, for webscraping, and it has been blacklisted.